# Generalized formula for sum of products.

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, arithmetic, numerical-linear-algebra, geometric-progressions

Q:The sum of all possible products of the first n natural numbers taken two by two   is?
 I did not understand the question as it is.What exactly is being asked?I'd really appreciate an answer explaining what is being asked along with a solution.

Comment: Why do you want a solution? Surely all you want is an explanation of what's being asked so you can think about it yourself.

Comment: (I have no idea what's being asked either, so can't help you there.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my book (where $0\in\Bbb N$) they would probably be asking for
$$
  \sum_{0\leq i<j<n}ij
$$
(but maybe they are negationists who deny $0\in\Bbb N$; then the conditions would be $0<i<j\leq n$ instead). "Taking two by two" usually refers to selecting unordered pairs of distinct elements from a set (here $\{i,j\}$, chosen such that $i<j$ to avoid having the same pair twice); for instance in the Chinese remainder theorem one requires the moduli to be "two by two relatively prime", which means any *pair* of *distinct* moduli is required to be relatively prime.

There is (independently of the $0\in\Bbb N$ issue) some ambiguity in their formulation though. Are the numbers $1\times 6,2\times3,3\times 2,6\times 1$ (all of which are equal to $6$), $4$ distinct products, or $2$, or just $1$? I've interpreted them as two products (not counting $2\times3$ and $3\times 2$ as different products), but one could defend there is only one product (namely $6$). The latter interpretation would make the question quite a bit harder (basically one is than taking the sum of all composite numbers up to $(n-1)n$, but including some primes $1\times p$ as well and excluding some squares; rather hard to handle exceptions).

Comment: it is not clearly mentioned in the question as to the number of distinct products.However when 2 distinct products were taken the answers matched.

Answer (score 1):

It is asked for $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{1\le i<j\le n} i\cdot j$.

*Hint:* Think of $(1+2+\dots+n)^2$.

Comment: The formulation is not very clear, but I don't think they want to include the products $i\cdot i$, and I doubt whether they want to include $i\cdot j$ and $j\cdot i$ separately, which would just make the result twice as large.

Comment: I know,  I just forgot to write it.Thanks for pointing it.