# General formula for the sum of $k$-products

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, symmetric-polynomials

I try to obtain a formula for the sum $$\sum_{1\le i_1 < i_2 < \dots < i_k \le n} i_1 i_2 \dots i_k$$
with $1\le k \le n$.

The case $k=2$ is asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1226652/generalized-formula-for-sum-of-products). Following the hint there, I expand $(1+2+\dots+n)^2$ and using the formula for $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2$ I was able to get the formula. For the case $k=3$, I expanded $(1+2+\dots+n)^3$ and by adding some terms I obtained a formula -which took a lot more time than the latter case-. However, I wonder how can I obtain a general formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), the sum equals the coefficient of $x^{n-k}$ in $(x+1)\cdots(x+n)$, which is equal to ${n+1\brack n+1-k}$ using [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Definitions) (compare with [this result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Expansions_for_fixed_k)).